# In Oracle database, what is the $ - notation?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
SELECT (space_limit/1024/1024) "Max Size (MB)",
       (space_used/1024/1024)  "Current Size (MB)"
 FROM v$recovery_file_dest;
```

Here you have `v$recovery_file_dest`, what does the `$` mean here? I see `v$` a lot, and was wondering if it means anything specifically.

Comment: It means nothing, it's just part of the name.

Comment: `what does the $ mean here` Nothing special. This just the way Oracle decided name its dynamic performance views and fixed tables (`x$` tables)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have mentioned in comments, it doesn't mean anything per se; as the 7th point in the [database naming rules](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements008.htm); `$` is indeed just another valid character.

The concepts guide has a section on [dynamic performance views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/datadict.htm#CNCPT1220), which says:

> `SYS` owns the dynamic performance tables, whose names begin with `V_$`.
>   Views are created on these tables, and then public synonyms prefixed
>   with `V$`. For example, the `V$DATAFILE` view contains information about
>   data files. The `V$FIXED_TABLE` view contains information about all of
>   the dynamic performance tables and views.

So it's just their naming convention for these views. You can get a list of those views, and that they do/tell you, from [the database reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_part.htm).

There's nothing stopping you, but it would probably be a good idea to avoid naming your own objects using the same convention, though I don't think you had any intention of doing so...